# Wrong prototype for a function

Tags: c++

I can't seem to know what I'm doing wrong. 
This is my function:

```
      void City::maxDistances(City A[], int numLines, int &indxCityA, int &indxCityB){
        int maxi = computeDistance(A[0],A[1]);
           for (int i =0; i < numLines; i++){
              for (int j = i +1; j < numLines; j++){...
```

I want to make a prototype for it:

```
void maxDistances( City[], int , int &, int &) ;
```

what is wrong with my prototype? The error is:

```
> prototype for void City::maxDistances(City*, int, int&, int&)' does not match any in class 'City'|
```

any help?

Comment: Is the prototype within the `class` declaration?

Answer (score 3):

This probably means the prototype is outside of the class declaration. It needs to be inside the class, e.g.

```
class City {
public:
    // ...
    void maxDistances(City A[], int numLines, int& indxCityA, int& indxCityB); 
    // ...
};
```

Comment: Can you post the entire class declaration (the relevant parts)?

Comment: @user2371916 you're **sure** it's inside the declaration of `class City`?

Comment: 'class City {
private:
    string name;
    double lat;
    double lon;
public:
    City() ;
   ~City() ;

    string getName() const ;
    double getLat() const  ;
    double getLon () const ;

    void setName(string)      ;
    void setLatitud (double)  ;
    void setLongitud (double) ;

double computeDistance(const City &A, const City &B) const ;

inline double deg2rad(double) const ;

void  display() const ;

void maxDistances( City[], int , int &, int &) ;

void minDistances( City[], int , int &, int &) ;



};
'

Comment: im new to this.. cant make the code look good.. but that's it.

Comment: i think the problem has to be the first parameter.. what do you guys think?

Comment: @user2371916 Why do you think that? That is fine (and should be easy to verify - remove it completely or change it to `City *`). Sidenote, to make text appear as code, enclose it in backticks (\`); for more check out the "help" link next to the comment input box.

Comment: @NikBougalis what could it be then? it doenst make sense. BTW, all these prototypes are in my header and the declaration in another cpp, just to point it out just in case.

Comment: @user2371916: I see nothing wrong with the code at all. Are you sure that you have your files saved correctly and that compiler is using the files you *think* it is?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldnt be using C-style arrays in C++ unless you have a VERY good reason, use std::vector instead (or the stl container that suits you best):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/

There is nothing wrong with the code you posted, it should work, the error is somewhere else, (verify that you are including the correct header file.).

Comment: They wont let me use vectors, i have to use what i know for now.

Comment: my header is this (part of it):
`
double computeDistance(const City &A, const City &B) const ;

inline double deg2rad(double) const ;

void  display() const ;

void maxDistances(City, int , int &, int &) ;

void minDistances(City, int , int &, int &) ;

`

Comment: void maxDistances(City, int , int &, int &) ; should be void maxDistances(City[], int , int &, int &) ;